# Assertions in Fortran

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, assert

Does Fortran have a standard function/keyword equivalent for C `assert`?

I could not find `assert` mentioned in Fortran2003 standard I have. I have found few ways how to use pre-processor, but in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759656/2838364) it is suggested to write own assertions. Is it possible to create such user function/subroutine without using pre-processor?

I expect that these assertions are disabled for release builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such statement or function/subroutine in Standard Fortran. But - as you have said - you can use your own subroutines/function and/or OOP in Fortran to realize this goal. See Arjen Markus' excellent [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/2502932.2502933) on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

Conditional compilation has never really caught on in Fortran and there isn't a standard pre-processor.  If getting your pre-processor to switch in and out a dummy assert routine isn't something you want to tackle you could ...

Define a global parameter such as:

```
logical, parameter :: debugging = .true.
```

If you are of a nervous disposition you could put this into a module and use-associate it into every scope where it is needed; to my mind using a global parameter seems a reasonable approach here.

Then write guarded tests such as

```
if (debugging) call assert(...)
```

Once you want to release the code, set the value of `debugging` to `.false.`  I expect, though I haven't tested this so you may care to, that any current Fortran compiler can remove dead code when it encounters an expression equivalent to

```
if (.false.) call assert(...)
```

and that your released code will pay no penalty for a dummy call to an `assert` routine.

Another approach might be to create a module, let's call it `assertions`, along these lines:

```
module assertions

contains

  subroutine assert_prd(args)
    ! declare args
  end subroutine

  subroutine assert_dbg(args)
    ! declare args
    ! now do do some assertion checking and exception raising, etc
  end subroutine

end module assertions
```

You could then rename the subroutines when you use-associate them, such as:

```
use, non_intrinsic :: assertions, assert=>assert_dbg
```

and change that to `assert=>assert_prd` when you want to turn off assertion checking.  I suspect though that compilers may not eliminate the call to the empty subroutine entirely and that your production code might pay a small penalty for every assertion it encounters.

Beyond this, see the paper by Arjen Markus that @AlexanderVogt has referred you to.

Comment: Another possiblity would be to have two implementations of assert function in two different files (assert_debug.f90 , assert_rel.f90) and choose the correct file in build system depending on Release/Debug build.

Comment: It seems better to me to switch between the assert functions with by changing a single line in the assertions module. To do this, add an `interface assert` with a `module procedure assert_dbg` that you can change to `module procedure assert_prd`.

Answer (score 2):

For **fixed form sources**, one can use `-fd-lines-as-comments` for release builds and `-fd-lines-as-code` for debug build (Intel Fortran `-d-lines`)
and use custom assert:

```
D      if (assert_condition) then
D         write(*,*) 'assert message'
D         call exit(1)
D      endif
```